# JScrollPane not getting larger when JLabels are added to panel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane

my problem is that although the scroll bar is appearing on the specific panel I want it to it's not extending as labels are added. I would like it to extend when the labels start going off the panel that they are being added to.

I have a main JPanel 'panel' which uses GridBagLayout, within that I have 5 other panels, the ones that needs a scroll bar is boardPanel which has null value for setLayout()

```
panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

...


1Panel = new JPanel();
1Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 800));
1Panel.setLayout(null);
scrollPanel = new JScrollPanel(1Panel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

...

c.weighty = 1.0;
c.weightx = 0.6;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.gridheight = 3;
panel.add(scrollPanel, c);

...
```

I hope this is enough information, thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a null layout!!!

Don't use setPreferredSize()!!!

Scrollbars will appear when the preferred size of the component is greater than the size of the scroll pane. By hardcoding a size you break this functionality.

Use a layout manager and the preferred size will change dynamically as you add components to the panel.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)